# Too many open files using NWListener on macOS

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to create an app that listens for incoming data on a UDP port using NWListener. This works fine until 248 messages are received - at which point the app crashes with the error message `nw_listener_inbox_accept_udp socket() failed [24: Too many open files]`.

This (I think) relates to the file descriptor limit and so I tried resetting the NWListener within a safe count of 100, but the problem still persists. This seems clumsy and I'm not sure it's actually possible within a receive.

How can I truly reset it such that it releases any open files?

Full code below, which is instantiated within a SwiftUI content view using:

```
.onAppear() {
  udpListener.start(port: self.udpPort)
}
```

Full class:

```
import Foundation
import Network

class UdpListener: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    private var listener: NWListener?
    private var port: NWEndpoint.Port?
    
    @Published var incoming: String = ""
    @Published var messageCount: Int = 0
    
    func start(port: NWEndpoint.Port) {
        
        self.port = port
        
        do {
            let params = NWParameters.udp
            params.allowLocalEndpointReuse = true
            self.listener = try NWListener(using: params, on: port)
            self.listener?.stateUpdateHandler = {(newState) in
                switch newState {
                case .ready:
                    print("ready")
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
            self.listener?.newConnectionHandler = {(newConnection) in
                newConnection.stateUpdateHandler = {newState in
                    switch newState {
                    case .ready:
                        self.receive(on: newConnection)
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
                newConnection.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "new client"))
            }
        } catch {
            print("unable to create listener")
        }
        self.listener?.start(queue: .main)
    }
    
    func receive(on connection: NWConnection) {
        connection.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data, !data.isEmpty else {
                print("unable to receive data")
                return
            }
            
            let date = Date()
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.messageCount = self.messageCount + 1
                self.incoming = formatter.string(from: date) + " "  + String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self) + "\n" + self.incoming
            }
            
            if self.messageCount == 100 {
                print("Resetting")
                self.listener?.stateUpdateHandler = nil
                self.listener?.newConnectionHandler = nil
                self.listener?.cancel()
                self.listener = nil
                self.start(port: self.port!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many times the start func is called? Also if you do `ulimit -n` in terminal, what number will you get?

Comment: start func is only called once when my main view is drawn (.onAppear). My file descriptor limit (ulimit -n) is 256, but increasing this will only delay the problem for a longer period I guess?

Comment: probably yes, considering 256 should be enough. You are opening some connections and you are not closing them when you don't need them. I'll see if i can find something...

Comment: Did you manage to replicate the problem @MahdiBM?

Comment: No unfortunately.